# Is module.export = [] bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two modules, both of which need to access a shared array. I solve this by having a module which just consists of the following:

sharedArray.js

```
module.exports = [];
```

In the modules I use it like this:

module1.js

```
var arr = require('./sharedArray');

function addSomething() {
    // Add something to arr 
}
```

module2.js

```
var arr = require('./sharedArray');

function doSomething() {
    // Use arr for something
}
```

This works but feels wrong (useless empty module) and that I'm missing something obvious.

Is there a better way to do it or is this actually how you solve it?

Comment: This is just the standard mechanism Node.js uses. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I updated my question. Basically it feels strange making a file and module that's more or less empty just for that. I've never seen anyone else do it.

Comment: I've done it before to avoid circular dependencies. Just be sure to name your module clearly and/or leave a comment explaining what data it is used for and maybe some examples of data consuming/producing modules.

Comment: nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just want to point out again that the file is nothing more than `module.exports = []`. It's not just for the example here. I think that's what made me think twice about it, that maybe it shouldn't even be a module on its own since it didn't contain any initial data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bad practice.  It is just one of several options for sharing data among modules.  There is nothing "wrong" with doing it the way you are doing it.

---

When sharing data among modules in node.js, you basically have three choices:

1. You can have one module that assigns the data to the global namespace when loaded.
2. You can have a method of some module that returns a reference to the data.  The method could be the module constructor or some other method.
3. You can make the data be part of a static data structure that is in the module exports.  This is essentially what you are doing now where you just make the whole exports be your array.

All three are perfectly legitimate ways of sharing the data.

The global data has the typical downsides of using globals (impacts the global namespace and potentially conflicts with a module that isn't even trying to use this particular data).

You could use the 2nd option when you were doing many other things with the module also or if you were generating the data upon demand rather than declaring it statically.

For the third option, if you made the module return an object and had the array be one property in that object that would make your module more extensible because then you could have other shared elements in that module also.  But, it works as you have it, it just isn't very extensible.

---

I personally would probably go for the more extensible option so you could have other shared items there also:

sharedData.js

```
module.exports = {
    myData: [...],
    myOtherData: [...]
};
```

module1.js

```
var arr = require('./sharedData').myData;

function addSomething() {
    // Add something to arr 
}
```

module2.js

```
var arr = require('./sharedData').myData;

function addSomething() {
    // Add something to arr 
}
```